# UIStackView with UILabels in Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, uilabel, uistackview

Since I've updated to Xcode 7.3 I have a problem with `UIStackView`. If I create an empty project and just put two `UILabel`s in `UIStackView` with default hugging and compression priorities, it shows me AutoLayout misplacement error. It even doesn't work with one(!) `UILabel` in `UIStackView`, so priorities doesn't matter (as I think, maybe there is the problem).

As I remember in Xcode prior 7.3 everything was fine. I checked on two MacBook Pro separately, it's the same issue.

Does anybody know how to fix it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why this was down voted? I find it perfectly useful and specific.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]
This is a bug appears in Xcode 7.3, so you can ignore it as what he said matt.

**The problem**

The storyboard can not calculate the intrinsic content size of subviews when you use UIStackView

**Solution**

If you hate seeing warnings in your storyboard you can fixe it like below :

You should do these steps for each subview of your `UIStackView`

- Tap the warning of your subview
- Tap "Update frames" option
- Choose "Placeholder" of the subview intrinsic size in the fourth menu in the
  inspector view

Like that you will not see warnings, and you can see if any ambiguities exist

The disadvantage is you should do this steps each time you change your subview (example: changing the size of text of an UILabel)

Hoping that Apple fixes this bug in the next release

Comment: Hey Hamza. Thank you for your screenshots! It works like a charm! Awesome find!

Comment: Hey @RalfHundewadt, you are welcome, and thank you for your feedback :)

Answer (score 4):

Ignore the warnings. The storyboard has never quite understood stack views. The constraints will be correct at runtime and that's all that matters.

Comment: Yes, in runtime it works, but also was working until 7.3 in Interface Builder. Does Apple know the issue and do they plan to fix it? :(

Comment: Do you have the bug number? - So I can report it too as a duplicate :)

Comment: @matt how can I be sure the constrains are good are runtime? Is there a way I can check ambiguosity at runtime?

Answer (score 3):

I have a different trick for eliminating the warnings and making 'update frames' work properly.

**Advantage:**

Doesn't require changing placeholder values every time text changes

**Disadvantage:**

Extra views that are unnecessary when Xcode 8 comes out

**Steps:**

- Embed each UILabel inside a UIView.
- Constrain the UIView to size itself based on the label (match leading, trailing, bottom, and top)

It seems like UIStackView (in Xcode 7) can't understand the intrinsic content size of a label, but CAN understand the intrinsic content size of a view - so put the label in a view and presto!

[image]

Comment: Even on the current version of Xcode 8 (Beta 6) this is necessary sometimes. Bug filed.