# Misplaced Views in Interface Builder with UIStackView

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uistackview

I'm using `UIStackView`s in `Interface Builder` and I keep getting caution warnings because of `Misplaced Views`. Going to `Resolve Auto Layout Issues` and selecting `Updating Frames` in `All Views` doesn't work either. It throws my entire views way out of place within my `Storyboard` `Scene`.

If I run my application, the views are are positioned in the way I want them. My only issue is with those caution warnings within `IB`.

Any suggestions on how to completely satisfy these?

Comment: Usually I'd say to resolve all warnings/errors, but if it's running in your app, and keeps happening, it sounds like a bug in this case, and id advise not to worry

Comment: @Elloi It's a Xcode 7.3 bug, you can find here the solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/36941290/2477632
Hope that helps

Comment: @HamzaGhazouani Thank you for the reference and for pointing that out! It certainly helps.