# Swift horizontal stackView looks odd in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, autolayout, uistackview

I have setup a horizontal stackView in my app that holds two labels.
One label has static content and the other label has dynamic content depending on json data. What I want is to center the total width of my two labels.

The stackView looks odd in the storyboard but fine in my simulator/device.

[image]

If I click on my stackView I get these orange lines, but they stay the same if I refresh the view in storyboard.
The stackView constraints is: `Center X to superview` and `buttom space 5`to the orange button bellow. So only two constraints.

And my StackView settings are `Alignment:Center` and `Distrubution:Fill`

I have no contraints setup for the labels inside.

But if I run my app it works and look like this in the simulator:

[image]

Both **Category** and **All Categories** have the same spacing to the superView.

So am I missing some contraint to my stackView since it wont display the same in the sotryboard?

Comment: did you try update frames on your storyboard?

Comment: I have this every time I use nested stack views in IB. I figure it's an Xcode bug. I've stopped using Stack Views in IB because of this (and the build warnings it emits).

Comment: It's a Xcode 7.3 bug, you can find here the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/36941290/2477632 Hope that helps