# How to set height of nested views in UIStackView in the right way

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, uistackview, xcode8

In my app there is a viewController placed inside a NavigationController and TabBarController. a viewController has 1 stackView inside.
I've dragged 3 items inside a stackView: UILabel, MKMapView and UILabel 
MKMapView is in the middle.
I want my MKMapView to be about 0.8% of the StackView Height (so that it would stretch if the device screen is big and shorten it's height if it is small) I want my UILabels to have a fixed height of 30px.
How to implement this the right way using constraints in Main.Storyboard.

Which way is the most appropriate?

I've tried to do it the following way:

1. I've added UIStackView and inserted UILabel, MKMapView, UILabel inside. My stackview now has (alignment: fill and distribution fill set)

[image]

2. After i've added the following constraints to UIStackView

[image]

3. I've changed the following properties in UIViewController because if not set, the UIStackView is hidden by TabBar and NavigationBar (maybe this can be fixed, do not know how)

[image]

4. My storyboard looks the following way after setting 1-3

[image]

5. Now when I want to set label1 and label2 height to 30px and when i do that i receive "frame will be different at runtime" error

[image]

What am i doing wrong? How to do this nesting with setting the heights of nested elements right? I'm using Xcode 8 beta 5 with Swift 3.

Comment: It's a Xcode 7.3 bug, you can find here the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/36941290/2477632 Hope that helps